# How do I implement this Material Design 2.0 button shape?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I would like to achieve the button shape looking like the one in Material Components example

[image: example]

What I already tried to do is setting custom style for the button like this

```
    <style name="ButtonAddLeft" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/secondary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ButtonAddLeftShape</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ButtonAddLeftShape">
        <item name="cornerFamilyTopLeft">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerFamilyBottomLeft">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">12dp</item>
    </style>
```

But this does not look like the one from the example, regardless of how I set the cornerSize.

Comment: How are you using these styles

Comment: Have a look at this, it might be helpful, https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/building-shape-system-for-material.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the corner cut style to the theme.

```
    <style name="RightCutButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/CornerCut</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CornerCut" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
        <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">18dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">18dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/CornerCut</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: It does work! Although there is a problem here - this has overridden all my buttons in that activity. Is there a way to prevent that? I also need the button which would be cut in opposite direction, is that doable?

Comment: Maybe there is a way to set the shape programatically from path? That would be the best way, I can't find anything about it tho.

Comment: Create a separate theme and set it to the button in the xml.

<style name="RightCutButton" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light">
<item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/CornerCut</item>
</style>

 Now, set this RightCutButton in the XML where you have declared the Button by using "android:theme="@style/RightCutButton" This overrides only for that particular button. @laszlo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`app:shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute in your layout:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ButtomShapeArrowRight"
        .../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ButtomShapeArrowRight">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">4dp</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">50%</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">50%</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

You can also achieve it programmatically:

```
MaterialButton button_arrow = findViewById(R.id.button_arrow);
button_arrow.setShapeAppearanceModel(
    button_arrow.getShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,..)
        .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,...)
        .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f))
        .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f))
        .build()
);
```

Just a note about `new RelativeCornerSize(0.5f)`: It changed in `1.2.0-beta01`. Before it was `new RelativeCornerSize(50))`.