# How to create 2 buttons with shape like this?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image: Button]

I've tried using relative layout as the container, but the result is still not as expected.

Comment: try [ShapeOfView](https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView)

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190528/create-custom-complex-xml-shape-android/61339071#61339071

Answer (score 0):

You can create two custom shapes and set them as the buttons background (`android:background="@drawable/sample"`)

Example for the first button

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="160dp"
    android:height="80dp"
    android:viewportWidth="52.652084"
    android:viewportHeight="21.166666">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#F44336"
        android:pathData="M31.214,0.036 L2.229,0.027C0.332,0.026 0.104,0.811 0.101,1.862l-0.047,16.618c-0.003,1.466 -0.185,2.731 1.932,2.729L51.342,21.175c1.381,0.096 1.798,-0.748 0.581,-2.647L45.639,9.214 40.544,1.907C39.687,0.67 39.285,0.305 38.061,0.138 36.744,-0.042 34.414,0.081 31.214,0.036Z"
        android:strokeWidth="1.11766827"/>
</vector>
```

To create the vector you can use software like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/), or [Illustrator](https://www.adobe.com/it/products/illustrator.html)

---

Another option is to create two button in a `LinearLayout` and use the [Shape Theming](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/shape) to set a custom style with a cut `cornerFamily` and the size you wish.
Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55613877/16279195) for a good example.